# Compare attribute does not validate properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I try to compare two TimeSpan fields. Code below doesn't works. Also, I remove [DataType(DataType.Time)] and try without any success.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required start time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Compare("EndTime", ErrorMessage = "Početak i kraj smjene moraju biti različiti.")]
    public System.TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required end time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public System.TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
```

How to compare two TimeSpan fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare validates the values are the same. are you sure you want the start and end times to be the same value? also how are the values set? it may be that they are off by a millisecond or two and therefore not equal.

Comment: Aaaaaa..... You are right.I'm shame. Ok, How to validate that two fields where they need to be different?

Comment: either roll your own or use an existing 3rd party library

Answer (score 0):

Check out FluentValidation, I was shown this and it works great.

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/